# C# UWP: Help Creating an app: User Upload MP3 file to be stored and played from a list

Tags: c#, uwp, upload, mp3

I am currently creating a UWP app in visual studio using C# and XAML that would mimic a music library.

The app will allow the user to upload MP3 files on one page and then the user will be able to click to another page to play this music from a list organized by title, artist, and album name. Therefore, I'd need to reference the metadata of the MP3 file to be able to place the songs into the list under their respective titles, artist names, and album names.

Can anyone provide me help with how to store the music that the user has uploaded?
Also how to reference the metadata from the MP3 file to bind the title, album name, and artist to headers of a list?

Apologies if this has already been sorted out in previous questions on stackoverflow. I searched through a few searches, but didn't find anything that was applicable.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the user supposed to be able to access previous uploaded songs after they have closed and reopened the app? Or should they only be able to access songs they have uploaded in the current session?

Comment: @user1419778 Thank you for your comment. They’d have to be able to access previously uploaded songs as well as the ones they are currently uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like you are asking more than a single question here so i will try to address each one as best as i can.

1- The app needs to be able to access the MP3 files. If you are using an [OpenFilePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker) to "upload" the files to the app, then the app can keep a reference to the `StorageFile` which would be valid for as long as the app is open. If you want to allow your app to access the same files after it is closed and opened again, then you need to look into using [FutureAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions) but be careful as this list has a limit of 1000 items max. If you expect that your app will need to access more than 1000 files, then look into storing referenced to folder instead or allowing the app to access the user's [MusicLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders)

2- To read the MP3 file's metadata, You will need to use a library for that which is compatible with the UWP platform. For this, [TagLibSharp-Portable](https://github.com/timheuer/taglib-sharp-portable) is preferred. The link provided has a sample on how to read the tags from the file.

Hopefully this puts you on the right path to implement your features.

Answer (score 0):

I think I encountered this question before when helping a friend, for reading/writing meta data of an audio/video, read more about [TagLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/).

```
string fileName = @"D:\Personal\MyMusic\Acoustic Covers\Song1.mp3";
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(fileName);
Console.WriteLine(file.Tag.Title);
Console.WriteLine(file.Tag.Album);
```

Then for storing song data to db, should store it as bytes.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        // store to db.
    }
}
```

I have not tested the code, I was just imagining while writing it, but this should help you start your project.